# How can I show the third level items?

Tags: css

I want to create a multilevel dropdown menu for a blog and use this custum css3 style for it.

```
#contact-links {
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
#contact-links a {
    color: #4C9FEB;
}
#contact-links a:hover {
    color: #3D85C6;
}
#my-links {
    float: right;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 4px 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;
}
#my-links a {
    margin-left: 7px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#my-links a:first-child {
    border-width: 0;
}
#menu-container {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f6f6f6, #e9eaea) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#f6f6f6, #e9eaea) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    background: linear-gradient(#f6f6f6, #e9eaea) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f6f6f6', endColorstr='#e9eaea',GradientType=0 );
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    box-shadow: -1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) inset;
    clear: both;
    height: 46px;
    padding-top: 1px;
}
#neat-menu {
    float: left;
}
#neat-menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#neat-menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#neat-menu > ul > li {
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
}
#neat-menu ul li a {
    box-shadow: -1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) inset, 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) inset;
    border-color: #D1D1D1;
    border-image: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 1px 0 0;
    color: #333333;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    padding: 11px 15px 10px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;
}
#neat-menu ul li a:hover {
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#efefef, #e9eaea) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#efefef, #e9eaea) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    background: linear-gradient(#efefef, #e9eaea) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#efefef', endColorstr='#e9eaea',GradientType=0 );
}
#neat-menu > ul > li.active > a {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#55A6F1, #3F96E5) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#55A6F1, #3F96E5) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    background: linear-gradient(#55A6F1, #3F96E5) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#55A6F1', endColorstr='#3F96E5',GradientType=0 );
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2D81CC;
    border-top: 1px solid #4791D6;
    box-shadow: -1px 0 0 #55A6F1 inset, 1px 0 0 #55A6F1 inset;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: -1px 0 -1px -1px;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#neat-menu > ul > li.active > a:hover {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#499FEE, #3F96E5) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#499FEE, #3F96E5) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    background: linear-gradient(#499FEE, #3F96E5) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#499FEE', endColorstr='#3F96E5',GradientType=0 );
}
#neat-menu > ul > li:first-child > a {
    border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
}
#neat-menu ul ul {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#F7F7F7, #F4F4F4) repeat scroll 0 0 padding-box transparent;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#F7F7F7, #F4F4F4) repeat scroll 0 0 padding-box transparent;
    background: linear-gradient(#F7F7F7, #F4F4F4) repeat scroll 0 0 padding-box transparent;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#F7F7F7', endColorstr='#F4F4F4',GradientType=0 );
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF inset;
    height: 0;
    margin-top: 1px;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 240px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -ms-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
}
#neat-menu ul li:hover ul  {
    margin-top: 0\2;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
#neat-menu ul ul a {
    border-right-width: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #D1D1D1;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF inset;
    color: #444444;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    padding: 7px 12px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;
}
#neat-menu ul ul a:hover {
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#55A6F1, #3F96E5) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#55A6F1, #3F96E5) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    background: linear-gradient(#55A6F1, #3F96E5) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#55A6F1', endColorstr='#3F96E5',GradientType=0 );
    border-top: 1px solid #4791D6;
    box-shadow: -1px 0 0 #55A6F1 inset, 1px 0 0 #55A6F1 inset;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#neat-menu ul ul li:first-child a {
    border-top-width: 0;
}
#menu-search {
    margin:8px 10px 0 0;
    float: right;
}
#menu-search form {
    background: url("http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-NzU9je1udG4/Uw-1tZku4eI/AAAAAAAAGWs/-h4BU1mFTiU/s1600/menu-search.gif") no-repeat scroll 5% 50% transparent;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) inset, 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;
    height: 26px;
    padding: 0 25px;
    position: relative;
    width: 130px;
}
#menu-search form:hover {
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
}
#menu-search form input {
    color: #999999;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 26px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: medium none;
    float: left;
    outline: medium none;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#menu-search form input.placeholder, #menu-search form input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #C4C4C4;
}
```

The problem is that when I add a third level item in my menu it doesn't show it.
How can I show and use the same style the 3rd level items?

Comment: Offtopic, but it will increase readability: all `-moz-transition` & `-moz-linear-gradient` can be removed, FF supports the proper `transition` and `linear-gradient` now. The `filter: progid...` is IE8 AND SLOW TO PARSE. Suggest you remove that as well and provide a sortof fallback for users who are stuck in windows XP

Comment: This should do about the same as your code does, more compacter and removed unneeded lines and attributes: https://jsfiddle.net/kzwswrjf/